# Why does my javascript get commented

Tags: javascript, html, browser

So im working on this TinyMCE javascript, it should be pretty straight forward, but here's the deal. When I look at my page source this is what I see

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
tinyMCE.init({
mode : "exact",
elements : "content",
theme : "advanced",
skin : "o2k7",
skin_variant : "blue",
plugins : "advimage,advlink,contextmenu,fullscreen,inlinepopups,nonbreaking,paste,preview,print,safari,style,table",
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,preview,print,fullscreen,code",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
theme_advanced_resizing : true,
fullscreen_new_window : true
});
// -->
</script>
```

Can someone please explain to me why my browser (FF and IE) puts the comment around my script? Script seems to work correctly though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML comments are there to prevent older browsers showing the JavaScript as text. Old browsers will treat your JS code as one long HTML comment. On the other hand, new JavaScript-aware browsers will normally interpret JS code between the tags  and  (the first and last lines of your JS code will be treated by the JavaScript interpreter as one-line comments).

Comment: "Older" meaning "ancient" or "text-mode". I don't think any browsers from over the last decade are graphical and don't support JS.

Comment: What was the last browser to have issues with JavaScript without the comments, Navigator 3?

Comment: I have to admit that I can't think of a browser that wouldn't interpret the JavaScript as what it is, however TinyMCE are a more paranoid than you and I

Comment: Thank you Mike. That makes sense, but I still don't understand why the latest IE and FF would put these comments in, they clearly support javascript :) So if the browser (being new) supports javascript, why does it still put the comments in? Isn't that kindda redundant? Or is it actually something that TinyMCE puts in?

Answer (score 1):

The comment  block only applies to HTML. This was common practice in the early days of web development where some browsers didn't support JavaScript so the code was commented out so it wouldn't be printed to screen.